# How to use "bank on something" idiom?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I'd bank on something that is mango tree.

Is the above sentence correct or need any corrections?

I gone through this [page](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bank+on), but most of examples related to money bank & also all sentences are in future tenses, doesn't allow me to think freedom about this idiom.

Comment: The sentence does need corrections.  What are you even trying to convey with it?  "Bank on" basically means "depend on" - for example, "When I quit my old job, I was banking on finding a new job quickly" means that I left my old job assuming that I could find a new one quickly.

Comment: -1 for the misleading claim that “most of the examples [are] related to money bank.” That’s poppycock. _I don't think you can bank on Tom coming tonight—he's really unreliable. I will be there on time – you can bank on it. I need a promise of your help – I hope I can bank on it. All I can bank on is that when I tell Dad what happened, he'll know what to do. You can bank on Molly's caterer to do a good job. You can bank on her to get the job done when it has to be done quickly. I wouldn't bank on the bus arriving on time._ Those example sentences have nothing to do with a money bank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your sentence is not quite right

> I'd bank on something that is mango tree.

rather it should be

> I'd ***bank on it***, that is **a** mango tree.

The idiom

> *(you can)* [bank on it](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/14/messages/616.html)

means it is a *sure thing* and *certain*

> like ***money in the bank***

or

> you can ***take that to the bank***

which is the title of the 1981 hit song by Shalamar

> [Take That To The Bank](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRF8yWSelWw)

Comment: ha, love Shalamar

Comment: Bit of pop culture for the language learners.

Comment: It's the right way to end an answer.